# Is it possible to prevent an unknown javascript script from being able to make a network call in a browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, browser

If I'm loading arbitrary external javascript code in a browser setting, is it possible to ensure it can't make the browser run make any ajax calls or network requests?

Comment: "Possible" using what, javascript? Extremely unlikely given that loading any resource causes network traffic (images, linked style sheets, frames, objects, scripts, etc.). It may be possible via the UI if your browser provides functionality to limit certain types of object making network calls, but you will never be certain unless you disable your network connection.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you prevent any resource calls? - No.** (haven't explored the ['extension'](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) route though)

Since even an `<img src='any valid url'>` creates a resource request which your code cannot prevent.

**Can you prevent ajax calls? - Yes, to an extent.**

Assuming that you want to ensure that any third party libraries shouldn't make any arbitrary ajax calls (cross domain), you will simply ensure that you don't [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) in your web server.

Your own application code can make ajax calls since they are in your domain only. However, you can [filter those calls on server](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm) to check for specific properties like purpose, credentials, etc

It may be worth exploring [google caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) (haven't tried that myself)

Comment: Well you could prevent someone from resource calls if you were ok with removing someone's access to the dom entirely, right?